# Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'

Tags: etherscan, bsc, pancakeswap, bscscan

I'm trying to swap a BNB for BUSD using pancake swap and quick nodes but I am getting a error when doing the swap.

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x47c73f99aa901596e7c53208c28979c63384f92757f521b3e3dc7427df41fa7c

I am a beginner and I am having trouble understanding the other solutions. I have been trying to solve this problem for 3 days now and nothing seems to work.

This is currently my code

```
    const routerContract = new ethers.Contract(
    router,
    [
        'function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns(uint[] memory amounts)',
        'function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint256 amountOutMin,address[] path,address to,uint256 deadline )',
        'function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn,uint amountOutMin,address[] calldata path,address to,uint deadline) '
    ],
    signer
);


const bnbContract = new ethers.Contract(
    WBNB,
    [
        'function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)'
    ],
    signer
)


    const BNBamountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits('.01', 18);
    let amounts = await routerContract.getAmountsOut(BNBamountIn, [WBNB, BUSD]);
    console.log(amounts[1])
    console.log(amounts[1].div(10))
    var amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(10));

    console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(BNBamountIn));
    console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(amountOutMin));

    amounts[0].approve(router, BNBamountIn)
    const approveTx = await bnbContract.approve(
        router,
        BNBamountIn
    );
    let reciept = await approveTx.wait();
    console.log(reciept);
    const swapTx = await routerContract.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        BNBamountIn,//ammount were putting in
        amountOutMin,//the lease ammount were expectng
        [WBNB, BUSD],
        ME,
        Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20,
        {
            gasPrice: provider.getGasPrice(),
            gasLimit: 310000,
        }
    )

    

    let receipt = await swapTx.wait();
    console.log(receipt);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: It fails quite early. The router trying to transfer WBNB to itself from the sender. The account has BNB. If you really want to swap BNB then you must call `swapExactETHForTokens`.

Comment: You have not required amount of WBNB on your wallet.

Comment: I tried swapExactETHForTokens and I'm still getting the same error. and I definitely have enough WBNB in my wallet.